# Question about inner measure

Tags: measure-theory

I need to prove that for every $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$:

$m_*(A)+m_*(B)\geq m_*(A\cup B) +m_*(A\cap B)$

(When $m_*$ is the inner measure).

I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: So, what do you know about the inner measure?